# Как написать драйвер клавиатуры под Mac, Win и Linux?

Tags: драйвер, клавиатура

Есть специфическая железка самодельная, с клавиатурой. Есть желание написать драйвер, чтобы, набирая текст на этой чудо-клаве, текст появлялся в редакторе. Соответственно чтобы работала в разных ОС.

К сожалению, пока никакой информации про разработку клавиатуры, драйвер клавы под ОС не нашёл.
Пока не понятно, как решить вопрос с кодировкой, символами, раскладкой и как весь процесс происходит от нажатия до появления символа на экране.

Прошу подсказать, что почитать, поизучать, и есть ли какие-нибудь наработки.

Comment: А как железка подключается?

Comment: @eicto, по USB. Могу сделать и, возможно, позже сделаю подключение по Bluetooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никаких драйверов не нужно. USB устройство, а именно микроконтроллер, должно уметь общаться по [USB HID](http://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_HID). Если устройство на базе AVR, посмотрите конструктор tmk_keyboard или библиотеки V-USB, LUFA и т.п. В ВК есть [сообщество](http://m.vk.com/klavarog), где вы можете спросить, найти помощь по вопросу.
Разрешите полюбопытствовать, что за устройство?